# RequireJS and Karma

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, karma-runner

I am trying to set my project up to use karma/jasmine. This project also uses knockoutjs (shouldn't really matter) and requirejs (really matters). The project structure is a little different from the norm and that's what is giving me issues. I am running this using `karma start` from the command line.
I tried to follow the [karma requirejs setup instructions](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html) which I feel got me most of the way there. I can set it up to load the test/spec files correctly or the src files correctly but not both. In its current state, I get the following message:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9876/base/app/test/components/home-pageSpec.js`

If I change the baseUrl in test-main.js (generated by `karma init`) from `'/base/app'` to `'/base'`it works just fine until I have a relatively address require.

home.js working (no relative require):

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    function HomeViewModel()
    {
        this.name = 'myName';
    }

    return {viewModel: HomeViewModel};

});
```

home.js not working (relative require):

```
define(['jquery', 'js/services/someService'], function ($, someService) {
    function HomeViewModel()
    {
        this.name = 'myName';
    }

    return {viewModel: HomeViewModel};

});
```

Which gives the following error `GET http://localhost:9876/base/js/services/programService.js`. This is because the resource is really at (or should be at) `http://localhost:9876/base/app/js/services/programService.js`

```
.
├── app
│   ├── bower_modules ...
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   └── home.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── lib ...
│   │   ├── services
│   │   │   └── someService.js
│   │   ├── require.config.js
│   │   ├── router.js
│   │   └── startup.js
├── bower.json
├── gulpfile.js
├── karma.conf.js
├── node_modules ...
├── package.json
├── test
│   └── components
│       └── home-pageSpec.js
└── test-main.js
```

Please tell me how to fix the relative path stuff please.

karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Apr 15 2015 10:07:13 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'test-main.js',
      //{pattern: 'app/bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/bower_modules/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/js/lib/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/**/*Spec.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/components/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'app/js/services/**/*.js', included: false}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'app/bower_modules/**/tests/*',
      'app/bower_modules/**/spec/*',
      'app/bower_modules/**/meteor/test.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

test-main.js:

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function(path) {
  console.log(path + "********");
  var p = path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
  console.log(p + "********");
  return p;
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
  }
});

require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base',

  paths: {
    "jquery":                       "app/bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
  },

  // dynamically load all test files
  deps: allTestFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

home-pageSpec.js:

```
define(['app/components/home/home'], function(homePage) {
  var HomePageViewModel = homePage.viewModel;

  describe('Home page view model', function() {

    it('should supply a friendly message which changes when acted upon', function() {
      expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });

  });

});
```